# How to generate a new random number in python without running the program again or add up new variable?

Tags: python, random

For so far, I've learnt how to use `randrange()` and `choice.random()` to generate random number. But there is something confusing me, that everytime I can only generate a fixed random number, like:

```
import random

x = [1,2,3,4]

chance = random.choice(x)

while chance < 5:
    print chance
```

At this example, the random number generate by chance is fixed. If I want to generate a new random number, I have to run this program again or to add up a new variable.

is there a method, that I can build something which I use it to generate new random numbers without to run the program again or add up a new variable?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why can't you rerun `chance = random.choice(x)`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that, it's ture return is much better here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    chance = random.choice(x)
    print chance
```

The line `chance = random.choice(x)` evaluates the expression `random.choice(x)` once, and assigns the result to the variable `chance`. After that, in your code you're just looking at `chance` repeatedly. That won't evaluate the expression `random.choice(x)` again.

Comment: This silently changes the semantics of his code in an irrelevant way. I think you want to add an `if chance >= 5: break`, or change the outer loop to `while chance < 5` and move the `chance =` after the `print`.

Comment: @abarnert: I'm reasonably sure `random.choice([1,2,3,4])` can't return a value greater than or equal to 5. I changed the code in order to indicate to the questioner that if he wants an infinite loop there's a better way to write one.

Comment: Sure, that's true, but clearly the OP didn't understand that, so if you make that change without explaining it, he won't realize why you did it, and will think it's part of the answer to what he asked rather than something totally separate.

Comment: @abarnert: that's fine, I prefer questioners to be rewarded if they try to properly understand the code in answers. SO is for programmers, not script kiddies. If the questioner does just copy and paste this without understanding it then it won't do any harm, since it has the meaning the questioner wants.

Comment: That's the whole point: The OP is more likely to understand your code if you only change the part of his code that's relevant.

Comment: Hello, Steve Jessop. Thank you for your effort. I wrote these code by myself. But I have a furthur question here, When you write down" While True:" what object is "While" examine here? I have no idea. By the way, I'd like to create a function or something, so that each time I use it, it can create a new random number. I think an infinite loop of creating random number isn't my intention here.

Comment: @Mario: it is examining a global object named `True`, which is built in to Python and whose value is true in `if` and `while` tests. `True` and `False` are the same values returned from tests like `==`, `<`, etc. If you need to know how to create a function, read a Python tutorial or introduction and ask a question about what you read if you don't understand. We can't have every Python programmer being taught every feature of the language by a separate question on SO.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'm learing python with LearnPythonTheHardWay and reached exercise 40 so far. I've know understand how While True works, but why can't While False work? Since Flase is always False, this should cause infinite loop, too.

Comment: @Mario: The whole point of a `while` loop is that it keeps executing as long as its condition is true. Since `False` is never true, that means it stops executing immediately. This is explained when `while` is introduced [in the official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming). If LearnPythonTheHardWay doesn't explain this, you may want to supplement it with another source.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as stated "evaluates the expression .. **once**" : in fact the `chance = random.choice(x)` does get [re-]evalauted in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a method, that I can build something which I use it to generate new random numbers without to run the program again or add up a new variable?

Well, yes, you *could* generate a lazy infinite iterator of random values and fetch them one at a time. But you don't want to do that.*

The key to avoiding having to "add up a new variable" each time is to just reuse the same variable:

```
chance = random.choice(x)

while chance < 5:
    print chance
    chance = random.choice(x)
```

---

* In case you're wondering: `for chance in takewhile(lambda i: i<5, (random.choice(x) for _ in count()):`. But notice that it's still doing the "reusing `chance` over and over, because that's the part that actually solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, dear abrnert, by using your method, it can creat new random number. But it's not "one", it's infinite.  I'd like to know how to design a function which every time I use it, it gives me a totally new random number. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Mario: `random.choice` already _is_ that function that, every time you use it, gives you a totally new random number. The loop above gets a new random number each time through the loop. So there's nothing else for you to do here.

Comment: I'm sorry. My module is a text D&D game, I'd like to make a function called dice. Each time I call this function inside other functions. It can produce a new random number. But by my current understanding, if I need to produce 1 more different random number, I have to create another new dice function. That's why I raise a question here.

Comment: @Mario: I'm not sure I understand your problem. You mean you want something like [this](http://pastebin.com/nbtG3TF3)?